# Obj-c How to inherit a method has array of arguments?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I understand the usage of key words "va_list" "va_start" "va_arg" "va_end".
And my supper class has a init method looks like this:

Super Class:

```
- (id) initWithChildren:(NSObject*)firstChild, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION{
    if(self = [super init]){
        va_list children;
        va_start(children, firstChild);

        self.children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstChild, nil];
        firstChild.father = self;

        NSObject* child;
        while ((child = va_arg(children, NSObject*)) != nil){
            [_children addObject:child];
        }
        va_end(children);
    }
    return self;
}
```

It works well.But I have trouble to inherit it.

Sub Class

```
- (id) initWithName:(NSString*)name children:(NSObject*)firstChild, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION{
    self = [super initWithChildren:"what should I write here?"];
    if (self){
        self.name = name;
        //other subclass work
    }
    return self;
}
```

Any ideas?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, your superclass needs to expose a designated initializer that takes `va_list` as a parameter. See [`vprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vprintf/) for an example of how it is done in the standard library.

```
- (id) initWithChildren:(NSObject*)firstChild, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstChild);
    id res = [self initWithChildren:firstChild varArg:args];
    va_end (args);
    return res;
}

- (id) initWithChildren:(NSObject*)firstChild, varArg:va_list args {
    // Do the actual initialization here
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is all discussed in the duplicate. :)

Comment: @rmaddy I saw the dupe only after posting the answer. Unfortunately, SO does not show incoming dupes as you type the answer.